# input type number while entering the value restrict range 0 to 1( decimal value can add )

Tags: angular, typescript

Input type number is restrict by range . i tried lot of thing , i didn't

```
  _keyPress(event: any, EditField, field) {
if (parseFloat(event.target.value) < 1 && event.keyCode != 46 && event.keyCode!= 8) {
  event.preventDefault();
}
}
```

Comment: Is it AngularJS (version 1), or Angular (version2+) ? Please keep the correct tag and remove the other.

Comment: angular 2+ @Pac0

Answer (score 2):

**return false;** after 'event.preventDefault' and change condition  <=1.